# Name of a full screen header jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm looking without success (maybe cause i don't know how to call this slider) a jQuery plugin to achieve that kind of header slider :

http://www.quaisdupolar.com/

It has to be smooth cause on my 27" scren the one used on this website isn't really smooth.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a "carousel." [Here's a round-up of them](http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=55) from a year ago.

Comment: Thanks nice collection, unfortunatly i don't see the same effect like on the webiste i gave.

Comment: @Tristan: Some of them have **lots** of options. For instance, "Chop Slider 2" has literally dozens of transitions, including a straight 2D slide very like the site you linked. You have to choose it from the options below the slider. (Sadly they don't do proper linking on the demos.) I found that in about 45 seconds of searching, so I expect others do similar.

Comment: I agree, one of those listed will surely be able to do what you need, if not you could always dig into the code of one to get the flash you are looking for between transitions.